# Set topic offset to value back in time for all consumers

Tags: apache-kafka

I have multiple consumers subscribed to one topic and all of them are in the same group. Sometimes it is necessary to force all the consumers to re-process some data which they already processed. In this case I have exact time to set consumer offsets to.

**Question:** Is there any mechanism in Kafka to set all consumer offsets to specified time? Here I mean that consumers must not be re-started, just their offsets should be magically set to new value and next poll requests would start fetching from new offset.

If it is impossible with standard Kafka, are there any ready libraries providing such a mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for a [`seek`](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/) method:

```
public void seek(TopicPartition partition, long offset)
```

> Overrides the fetch offsets that the consumer will use on the next poll(timeout)...

Comment: Seek works for one consumer. I need a solution that works for all consumers. Something like this:

allConsumersManager. setCurrentPosition(String group, String topic, long timestamp)